# Why isn't the map function iterating over the array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

I am using React, which I am new to and it says to use the map method to iterate over the array. When I do that the entire array logs to the console and not the individual words I want.

I am trying to call stock symbols when a user types them in the text box. But under the function `getSymbol()` the state of symbol is still an array even when I used map in render. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or what can I do to get single elements.

Here is my code:

```
class Symbol extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userInput: '',
            symbol: [],
            isLoaded: false
        }
    }

    typeSymbol = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            userInput: e.target.value.toUpperCase()
        }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.userInput)
        })
    }

    getSymbol = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(),
            this.setState({
                symbol: this.state.symbol

            }, () => {
                console.log(this.state.symbol)
            })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/symbol?exchange=US&token=${key}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (results) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        symbol: results
                    });
                    // console.log(this.state.symbol)
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        error
                    });
                }
            )
    }


    render() {
        const { symbol, userInput } = this.state
        if (userInput === symbol) {
            return (

                symbol.map((symbol, i) => (<span className="symbol" key={i}>{symbol.displaySymbol}</span>)),
                console.log('same')
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <div className="enterstock">
                    <h1 className="title">Enter Stock Symbol</h1>
                    <form className="inputfields" onSubmit={this.getSymbol}>
                        <input type="text" className="symfields" name="symbolname" onChange={this.typeSymbol}></input>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn">Send</button>
                    </form>
                </div >
            )
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, But I think your class name is colliding with a built in JS feature called [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol).

Comment: @JohnPavek Thanks for that info!

Answer (score 1):

You're using `symbol` in two different ways, and they're colliding. Try renaming the parameter of your `map()` function:

```
symbol.map((s, i) => (<span className="symbol" key={i}>{s.displaySymbol}</span>)),
```

`symbol` is not a reserved word in JavaScript, so you should be good there.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I am still getting the array.

Comment: Can you post the output and console log?

Comment: I posted the picture up top and I am using console.log(this.state.symbol) to render the output

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your if block. The map method works fine. What is happening is you are comparing the userInput(String) to symbol(an array) it will not work. I don't know what check you're trying to do. But if it is to check whether the userInput is in the array you're doing it wrongly.

```
import React from "react";
class Symbol extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  userInput: "",
  symbol: [],
  isFiltered: false,
  isLoaded: false,
 };
}

typeSymbol = (e) => {
this.setState(
  {
    userInput: e.target.value.toUpperCase(),
  },
  () => {
    console.log(this.state.userInput);
  }
 );
};

getSymbol = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const filter = this.state.symbol.filter(
  (el) => el.displaySymbol === this.state.userInput
);
// console.log(filter);
this.setState(
  {
    symbol: filter,
    isFiltered: true,
  },
  () => {
    console.log(this.state.symbol);
   }
 );
};

componentDidMount() {
fetch(`https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/symbolexchange=US&token=${key}`)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then(
    (results) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        symbol: results,
      });
      console.log(this.state.symbol);
      },
      (error) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        error,
      });
     }
   );
  }

 render() {
 const { symbol, userInput } = this.state;
 //console.log(userInput);
 if (this.state.isFiltered) {
  return symbol.map((symbol, i) => {
    return (
      <span className="symbol" key={i}>
        {symbol.displaySymbol}
      </span>
    );
  });
} else {
  return (
    <div className="enterstock">
      <h1 className="title">Enter Stock Symbol</h1>
      <form className="inputfields" onSubmit={this.getSymbol}>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="symfields"
          name="symbolname"
          onChange={this.typeSymbol}
        ></input>
        <button type="submit" className="btn">
          Send
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
  }
 }
}
export default Symbol;
```

Comment: Hi, this is what I thought i was doing wrong and you gave me the code but it's not working. I must be out putting the state of symbol wrong.

Comment: @ Jonathan Akwetey Okine Thanks for that information. How do I got about comparing the two then because I thought once you get a single element from map, it becomes a string.

Comment: @Alanaj I only gave you a suggestion but can tell me exactly what you want to do with your if condition so I assist?

Comment: @ Jonathan Akwetey Okine So, when a when a user types in the input field which is the userInput, they are supposed to press send and the corresponding symbol is supposed to match to the symbol that they typed in. It is supposed to return information about that stock symbol but right now I'm just returning the name.

Comment: @ Jonathan Akwetey Okine Thanks for all your help but that didn't work. I still have trouble accessing the array in the getSymbol function. It returns an object and I think I may be having trouble with the async call.